# Adding Gradle build Folder in library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to import a project as a library in android studio.
 I configured the build.gradle and the setting folder but I kept getting an error message saying that the configuration with the name default was not found. 
After doing research I found out that, the library requires a build.gradle folder. 
How do I add a build .gradle folder ?
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You should have this type of structure:

```
root
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  lib
    build.gradle
  app  //optional
    build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':lib' , ':app'
```

In `lib/build.gradle` something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion 22.0.1

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionName 1
        versionCode 1
    }
}
```

In `app/build.gradle` something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion 22.0.1

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionName 1
        versionCode 1

    }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':lib')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answer by @froger_mcs, he included a full tutorial of importing a library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio), the part that you're looking for is part **7.** hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you import your project as gradle project in Android Studio? Per default, every new project has a gradle file. This file only is missing, when you are coding without android studio.